# Move assignment is not called for member variable

Tags: c++11, visual-c++-2012

In the following code:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    vector<int> v;
};

MyClass f()
{
    MyClass x;

    x.v.resize(10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        x.v[i] = i;
    }
    return x;
}

void g()
{
    MyClass x;
    x = f();  // Copy assignment is called for vector<int>
}
```

compiled with Visual C++ 2012 in line `x = f()` I assumed that move assignment would be called for the vector. Instead I can see that the copy assignment is called. There are no copy/move assignment/constructor defined in the class, so I was hoping that the compiler would generate the default move assignment. If I use plain vector instead of `MyClass` the move assignment works fine. Is there something wrong with this code? Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you might have to define your own move constructor for `MyClass`, as [VS2012 doesn't do that for you yet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx): "'Rvalue references v3.0' adds new rules to automatically generate move constructors and move assignment operators under certain conditions. However, this is not implemented in Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2012, due to time and resource constraints."

Comment: @DyP Thank you. Neither does VS2013, unfortunately. I think your comment deserves to be the accepted answer.

Comment: Maybe, if it's right that adding a user-defined move ctor solves the problem. I can't test that with VS2012 atm.

Comment: * should have been an move-assignment op ;)

Comment: It does solve the problem. I tried it in VC2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx), VS2012 does not yet implicitly declare&define move-ctors and -assignment-ops:

> "Rvalue references v3.0" adds new rules to automatically generate move constructors and move assignment operators under certain conditions. However, this is not implemented in Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2012, due to time and resource constraints.

Therefore, you'll have to provide own, user-defined move-ctors and -assignment-ops (maybe `= default` suffices).

That said, and as [Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341970/ali) pointed out, `x = f()` should indeed call the move-assignment-op of `MyClass`, invoking the move-assignment-op of `vector`.

Answer (score 2):

**Your expectations are correct** and gcc 4.7.2 does generate the default move assignment, the

`vector& operator=(vector&& __x) noexcept(_Alloc_traits::_S_nothrow_move())`

is invoked, just as you expected.

So, as [DyP points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607551/move-assignment-is-not-called-for-member-variable#comment25631462_17607551), it is a not yet implemented feature in Visual Studio 2012.